# Merging disparate data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

So this issue involves merging two data frames of disparate length..

example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
p_i = data.frame(date=sample(1:40,20,replace=F),index_1 = runif(20,0,1),index_2 = runif(20,0,2))

p_i<-p_i[with(p_i,order(date)),]
w_d = data.frame(date=c(1:40),C=runif(40,2,38))
y_w <- seq(0, 40, length = 9)
x_w <- c(unique(p_i$date))


p_w <- ggplot(w_d, aes(x = date, y = C))+ 
    geom_bin2d(breaks = list(x = x_w, y = y_w))+
    scale_fill_continuous(low = "#99CCFF", high = "#CC0000", space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")


w_dat <- ggplot_build(p_w)$data[[1]]
```

What i'm trying to do is get the counts from "w_dat" merged into the "p_i" data frame, organized by date so I can regress either of the indices in p_i against the count in a given range, each range being a unique column.

Comment: You need a matching variable and then you can use one of the join functions from dplyr. Right now w_dat and p_i don't share any information so how do you know what goes where?

Comment: w_dat is based on w_d where I have the date column. The xmin or xmax column of w_dat would be information shared by both tables.

Comment: The range from `xmin` to `xmax` may have overlaps, i.e. you have xmin = 24 and xmax = 29 for both count = 1 and count = 2 (at least when I ran your example code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sorry, I confused `w_d` with `w_dat`*

You can use `dplyr` for that.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- full_join(p_i, w_d, by = "date")
```

If you also want to remove the rows with missings, use `filter(mydf, !is.na(index_1))`.

Comment: Yes, w_dat was really just my attempt at trying to coerce the two data frames into one. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: This is closer to what i'm trying to do, but not quite. I'm trying to introduce a set of columns into that new dataframe that correspond to a given range in w_d$C. What I want to fill the columns with is a count of instances within the date ranges from p_i (including counts of 0) where a range of values of w_d$C might occur. If C was temperature, the idea would be "How many measurements were taken within a given temperature range and a given time range?", the temperature ranges as columns, in this case the time range being based on the p_i dates and the temperature range being arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

So I adapted the answer Daniel provided to build the full data frame by including these lines:

```
w_sum<-ddply(w_dat, .(xmin,xmax,ymax), summarize,date=xmax,count=count)

mydf <- full_join(p_i, w_sum, by = "date")
```

this gives me a new new data frame which is effectively the intersection of the first two data frames.